# How can bind MySql database into a Datagrid (UWP)

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

i established a basic connection to a MySql Database following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/mysql-databases

```
    public MainPage()
    {


        this.InitializeComponent();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(
            "User ID = root; Password = ****; Initial Catalog = ****; Server = localhost"))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ****", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }

        this.DataContext = dt;

    }
```

now im trying to show the database content into a datagrid
and trying to find more related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sql data adapter.
edit: you can [map columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-datatable-and-datacolumn-mappings) if needed.

```
    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
```